# Android screen recorder with root

Tags: android, shell, adb

Can any one tell me how to record screen in Android tablet? Is there an app available for this?

I have installed and tried more apps in tablet. But I can't properly record the screen with animation.

I have used adb also but I got an issue in that:

```
shell@android:/ $ screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/demo.mp4
screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/demo.mp4
/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found
127|shell@android:/ $
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an Android device, not programming one.

Comment: http://andruboy21.blogspot.in/2014/02/capture-android-phone-screen-video.html

Comment: I have download it, but it shows error.

Comment: I'm annoyed that this question is getting ignored/voted down because I'm having the same problem: /system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found

Answer (score 0):

Plug in using microUSB.

In a command line, enter

`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/yourfilename.mp4` (Where yourfilename is can be whatever you want.)

When you're done, hit CTRL-C to stop recording.